# Simple partial differential equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I know this is a shame but I can't solve this simple partial differential equation. Can someone help me?  $$\frac{\partial ^2F(x,y)}{\partial x \partial y}=h(x,y) F(x,y)$$

Comment: Are you familiar with separation of variables?

Comment: There is no shame in asking a question but just let us know what have you tried so far

Comment: I thought of using the separation of variables method, but it did not seem to be the right one...